# Percentage of Total Amounts Based on Criteria

Tags: 2013, list, query

So here's my situation. I have a list used to track bids for a construction company. Each item represents a bid this company has submitted and includes the dollar amount, square yardage and status (pending, cancelled, got job, etc).

What I need to do now is find a way to present the users with a roll up of totals and percentages by status. Basically I need a way to find:

`Total dollars and Sq. Yds where status = "Pending"` - This can be done on the view using the "Totals" option.

The sticky part is I also need to show `Status "Pending" represents [x] percent of total dollars and sq. yds`

I've tried using a content query web part, no good there. I also tried using a separate list to keep a running tally whenever the parent list had an add/update/delete but the workflows got unwieldy and didn't work properly (I can't believe there's no `for each` for SP workflows). I saw some promising entries on using REST with workflows but the server doesn't have the 2013 workflow engine installed.

Is there a way to do this out of the box or am I going to be stuck writing a custom web part for this?

Comment: Does your OOTB requirement also include **not** using ClientSideRendering?

Comment: I honestly didn't know that was a thing. The last time I did any custom SharePoint development was for 2007.Very interesting.

Comment: If SharePoint 2013/Online is the latest Mustang, then SharePoint 2007 is the cart they drove around in the Roman Empire..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, do look into CSR and JSlink

An alternative is used here: [Calculate the average value of an array from sharepoint listitem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145100/calculate-the-average-value-of-an-array-from-sharepoint-listitem/145271#145271)

Comment: No joke, I was JUST looking at that question. That's exactly what I need. Thanks. I was about ready to install and crack open SSRS for the first time in over a decade, which I was absolutely NOT looking forward to.